# notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't call's onBindViewHolder() method

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView's Adapter, where I am adding items dynamically, when I am calling the my adapter's updateMessages function old data list were changing correctly but, recycler items stays the same.

this is my updateMessages method in my adapter:

```
fun updateMessages(messages: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>?){
    messages?.let {
       this.messages.clear()
       this.messages.addAll(messages)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

also here is complete adapter class, I don't understand what's the problem

```
class MessagesRecyclerAdapter(private val itemActionListener: IOnMessageItemActionListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val messages = ArrayList<MessageReceivedResponseModel>()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.awesome_chat_item, parent, false)
    return MyHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as MyHolder).updateUI(messages[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return messages.size
}

fun updateMessages(messages: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>?){
    messages?.let {
        this.messages.clear()
        this.messages.addAll(messages)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private inner class MyHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val messageTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_from_text_id) as TextView
    private val msgQuantityTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_quantity_txt_id) as TextView

    internal fun updateUI(msg: MessageReceivedResponseModel) {
        messageTextView.text = msg.from
        msgQuantityTextView.text = msg.quantity.toString()
    }
}

}
```

this is where my adapter and recycler initialization goes

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.activity_awesome_chat, container, false)
    recycler = view?.findViewById(R.id.awesome_chat_list_view_id) as RecyclerView
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recycler?.layoutManager = layoutManager
.....
}

override fun onMessageReceived(messages: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>){
        adapter?.updateMessages(messages)
        Log.e(TAG, messages.size.toString())
  }
// called in oncreateView of fragment
private fun initRecycler(items: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>?) {
    adapter = MessagesRecyclerAdapter(this)
    adapter?.updateMessages(items)
    recycler?.adapter = adapter
    Log.e(TAG, items?.size.toString())
}
```

Comment: try moving the updateMessages method to the activity where you using the adapter.

Comment: from my activity I'm calling adapter?.updateMessages(messages:List<MyMessageModel>)

Comment: can you show your activity where adapter is being used?

Comment: see onMessageReceived() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my problem where out of all this classes, The problem was in my interactor class where the messages retrieving requests started

```
fun startMessageRetrieveRequest(callback: OnRequestFinishedListener<List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>>){
    doAsync {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        val idx = Random().nextInt(2)
        val its: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>
        when(idx){
            0 -> its = REs
            1 -> its = RES_1
            else -> its = RES_1
        }
        callback.onResponse(its)
    }
}
```

I removed doAsync and works correctly, here callback.onResponse() is being called from Non-UI thread and it caused the problem `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`, but not always. Also app weren't crashed and I missed the log

Answer (score 0):

Try using `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, messages.size - 1);`.

```
fun updateMessages(messages: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>?){
    messages?.let {
        this.messages.clear()
        this.messages.addAll(messages)
        this.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, messages.size - 1)
    }
}
```

I think `notifyDataSetChanged()` isn't working because your dataset (`messages` field) is still the same object.

You can try to replace object of messages:

```
fun updateMessages(messages: List<MessageReceivedResponseModel>?){
    messages?.let {
        this.messages = messages
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized my problem

Answer (score -1):

You should use `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter, like this:
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` .
If you wanna use a class you can, you just need to declare the adapter variable as a member variable of the class and call the method like I said above. Where `adapter` is the name of your adapter.

Comment: He's updating the adapter within the adapter, no issue there.

Comment: you mean call the adapter notify method from fragment?

Comment: also if I pass the dummy data to the initRecycler() inside oncreateView()
like that initRecycler(listOf(MessageReceivedResponseModel("from",1)))
it works fine, but if I use this method inside onMessageReceived() method it doesnot works

Comment: Yes. Try to call notifyDataSetChanged(); after called call initRecycler. Maybe it doesn't work in the function

Comment: Can you post the entire onCreateView?

Comment: this is Adapter class https://gist.github.com/developer--/5fdf5aed8e063b4e2175d837ef7ae521 and this is fragment 
https://gist.github.com/developer--/cb2930e3ede2cadb48d3a83641d963ff

Comment: Try to call adapter.notifyDataSrtChanged after you call initRecycler in the onCreateView method. This way we understand if the method works fine or not