# OnBindViewHolder() doesn't call after setting unempty list from Room's Livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I've found similar problem [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969144/notifydatasetchanged-doesnt-calls-onbindviewholder-method), but there was not Room involved.

So I use LiveData throughout DAO-Repository-ViewModel (Room Version 2.2.3):

```
@Query("SELECT * from ...")    
fun getGoods(): LiveData<List<Goods>>
```

In my fragment there is subscribtion:

```
mViewModel.goodsList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {goodsList ->            
        mAdapter.setList(goodsList)            
    })
```

With logcat I can see that list is not empty.
Inside RecyclerView Adapter's setList() list is not empty as well.

```
fun setList(goodsList: List<Goods>) {
    records = goodsList        
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But method onBindViewHolder() is not called

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    // I can't get there
    viewHolder.bind(records[i])
}
```

I found 2 ways to solve the problem but they are hacks-like and I want to understand the better way:

1. Add a delay getting LiveData's onChange() in fragment:

   Handler().postDelayed({mAdapter.setList(goodsList)}, 200)
2. Switch context with coroutine's Dispatchers.Main getting LiveData's onChange() in fragment.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please add your onBindViewHolder() code to question

Comment: @Squti, added. I think it would be useless to show method bind()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this :

```
fun setList(goodsList: List<Goods>) {
    records = goodsList        
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

should be :

```
fun setList(goodsList: List<Goods>) {
    records.clear()
    records.addAll(goodsList)       
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

However I would think about using a `ListAdpter` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html with a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Goods>` callback.

Comment: clear/add with list items didn't help. I guess problem is not in adapter, but somewhere in LiveData observing

Comment: ListAdapter with DiffUtil helped. Thanks. Also this [link](https://github.com/vladsonkin/bikeindex/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/sonkins/bikeindex/features/bikes/filter/colors/ColorsAdapter.kt) was helpful